# Ejecutar aplicacion grafica desde Servicio Windows VBnet

Tags: vb, servicio, net

¿Es posible ejecutar una aplicación con interfaz grafica desde un servicio hecho con vb?

La idea es que revise si un programa se esta ejecutando, en caso de que no lo inicie.

he podido hacer que se ejecute una aplicación de consola, e incluso un .bat, pero no he podido hacer que inicie la aplicación con interfaz de usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente código si la aplicación está en el mismo path que tu aplicación

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("aplicación.exe")
```

De lo contrario deberías de especificar la ruta completa

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\xxxxx\xxxxxx\aplicación.exe")
```

Puedes incluso enviar parámetros, por si por ejemplo necesita un dato para abrirse tipo usuario poniendo una coma a continuación de la ruta o del nombre del programa y e parámetro entre comillas

```
("aplicación.exe", "parámetro")
```

Comment: ya lo realice así, me ejecuta la app de consola sin problemas, pero quiero que abra una aplicación con interfaz de usuario.


Incluso desde el servicio ejecuto una app de consola (sin problemas), de esta app de consola mando a ejecutar el comando **process.star,  shell o un batch ** directamente (estos últimos invocan a la app con interfaz) pero no abre visualmente... en algunos caso he visto que aparece en el administrador de tareas pero sin recursos asignados.

Comment: Es que contesté sin saber lo que habías realizado porque no lo mostraste. Casi mejor que pegues tu código y se pueda ver como lo hiciste, así quien sepa y pueda contestarte tendrá una visión un poco más amplia.